# Error: Value for argument "value" is not a valid query constraint. "undefined" values are only ignored inside of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Whenever I am trying to execute one query as follows :

```
const user = {
        userHandle: req.body.userHandle
    };

    db.collection('todos')
        .where('userHandle', '==', user.userHandle)
        .get()
        .then((data) => {
            let todos = [];
            data.forEach((doc) => {
                todos.push({
                    todoId: doc.id,
                    body: doc.data().body,
                    isDone: doc.data().isDone,
                    userHandle: doc.data().userHandle,
                });
            });
            return res.json(todos);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).json({ error: err });
        });
}
```

I get the below mentioned error in my google cloud console :

```
Error: Value for argument "value" is not a valid query constraint. "undefined" values are only ignored inside of objects.

at .Object.validateUserInput ( /workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:274 )
at .validateQueryValue ( /workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:2230 )
at .CollectionReference.where ( /workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1061 )
at exports.getAllTodoForOneUser ( /workspace/handlers/todos.js:29 )
at .Layer.handle ( /workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95 )
at .next ( /workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137 )
at .Route.dispatch ( /workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112 )
at .Layer.handle ( /workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95 )
at undefined. ( /workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281 )
at .Function.process_params ( /workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:341 )
```

Also I am trying to query with the body using POSTMAN as follows :

`{ "userHandle": "qmfUXw6YDwO9PQx1n13DjvPi2D23" }`

The following is the screenshot of my firebase db.

[image]

Comment: It's because `user.userHandle` is evaluating to `undefined` at line 5.

Comment: yes, I got the point but why ? every-time I am sending the body as `{ "userHandle": "qmfUXw6YDwO9PQx1n13DjvPi2D23" }` then why it is still evaluating as undefined ?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(req.body)` and checked if that values are present?

Comment: Yes I have. it's also giving me the correct value. Moreover it's running perfectly fine if I run it locally via `firebase serve`.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `where` constraint?

Comment: Have you tried to put the `req.body.userHandle` to the where query directly? e.g.: `.where('userHandle', '==', req.body.userHandle)`

Comment: @SoumyaKantiNaskar Make sure `req.body.userHandle` is evaluating to a string.